# What is "Tagged PDF"?

Tags: pdf, tagged-pdf

Can someone please explain what a "Tagged PDF" is, and how it differs from regular, non-tagged PDF?

Will tagged PDFs contain special content, such as XML, Rich Media, Javascript, or the like?

Which TeX-toolchains generate Tagged PDFs?

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Acrobat/9.0/Professional/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7cd8.w.html

Comment: Try here: https://taggedpdf.com/what-is-a-tagged-pdf/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Tagged PDF is a PDF file that contains meta-information around certain groups of PDF instructions inside a page content. This meta-information has many use cases: Text-extraction, content-reflow, document accessibility, geographic information in PDF containing maps, etc.

If you need to know more details about this topic I would recommend reading `Chapter 10 - Document Interchange` of [Adobe PDF Reference version 1.7](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell me how Tagged Pdf and PdfA/1A correlate ? Is a document "tagged pdf" if it has PdfA/1A format ?

Comment: Yes, for a document to be PdfA/1A, it must be a Tagged PDF among other  requirements.

Comment: Can tagged pdf have information about table cells , start & end of them??

Answer (score 4):

The main reason it is used is for accessibility. With the correct tags, a screen reader (for a blind person) can understand where headings fall, what is a table/footnote/graphic and so on. Also there is a feature called PDF Article Threading which is useful for magazine or newspaper layouts where an article is split across boxes/pages.